# Is it possible to make Ubuntu ask for my password before mounting USB drives?

Tags: security, usb-drive

I don't want anyone to be able to copy my files anyhow.

Is it possible to make Ubuntu ask for my password before mounting USB drives? If it is, how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try encrypting your usb drive on filesystem level. Take a look at [Ubuntu Community Help Wiki EncryptedFilesystemHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystemHowto). It explains in a quite detailed way the steps you have to take plus it has some examples.

Answer (score 0):

To ask **password** when you also mount **USB drives**,

1. Open Terminal (*Shortcut =* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).
2. Type

   ```
   sudo gedit /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla
   ```
3. Add `org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-*;` to **Line 3**.
4. Change **line 4**, `ResultActive=yes` to `ResultActive=auth_admin`.
5. After edits Lines **1 -4** will look like :

   ```
   [Mounting, checking, etc. of internal drives]
   Identity=unix-group:admin;unix-group:sudo
   Action=org.freedesktop.udisks.filesystem-*;org.freedesktop.udisks.drive-ata-smart*;org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount-system;org.freedesktop.udisks2.encrypted-unlock-system;org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-fstab;org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-*;
   ResultActive=auth_admin
   ```
6. Save and **Close** file.

Now Ubuntu will ask **password** each time before **mounting usb-drives**. Hope it helps.

This worked for me in **Ubuntu 20.04**.